# Need to clone repo after using bfg repo-cleaner or pull on existing?

Tags: git-rewrite-history, bfg-repo-cleaner

Reading the instructions for bfg repo-cleaner, the work flow seems like:

1. clone the repo using the --mirror option
2. strip the repo from unwanted items using bfg
3. use git gc to physically remove the items
4. do a push of the cleaned repo

However, then it is unclear to me whether you need to remove your own copy of the working directory and do a fresh clone, or whether you can just do a pull to get the clean repo/history? At the moment I am the only one who uses the repo.

Comment: You are right. This should be part of the main page of bfg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd be better off doing a fresh clone, as your old working directory will have dirty history that you don't want to risk pushing back into your newly cleaned repo.

Comment: Perhaps this info should be added in the the bfg page :-)

Comment: I've tweaked the text: https://github.com/rtyley/bfg-repo-cleaner/commit/41a9dd760

Comment: Can you elaborate on this process a little? Would we just do `git clone git://example.com/some-big-repo.git` in some folder and then replace the contents of our project's directory with the contents that we cloned (preserving any untracked files)?